# Why doesn't vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR have to return at least one present mode?

Tags: vulkan

The function `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR` has to return at least one format, [as described in the specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR.html):

> The number of format pairs supported **must** be greater than or equal to 1. `pSurfaceFormats` must not contain an entry whose value for `format` is `VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED`.

Why doesn't the same apply to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModesKHR`? I would assume that there should always be at least one present mode supported, as the [Valid Usage Requirements for this function](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModesKHR.html) require that the `surface` be supported by the `physicalDevice`:

> ### Valid Usage
>
> - `VUID-vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModesKHR-surface-06211`
>
>   `surface` **must** be supported by `physicalDevice`, as reported by `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR` or an equivalent platform-specific mechanism

Supporting the `surface`, I would imagine, would imply that presenting to it is possible, so a present mode should always be available. Perhaps this is an oversight in the specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always at least one present mode supported:

> `VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR` specifies ... This is the only value of `presentMode` that is **required** to be supported.

The standard just doesn't say it the same way.